# C# Win Form - Main thread not responding when using background worker

Tags: multithreading, winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0, backgroundworker

I have a **datagridview** which is being populated by a DataTable through **DataSource** and i am using a **backgroundworker** for formatting of cells (back color and forecolor of cells) in datagridview.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
private void Frm_Find_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CheckForValidValues();
}

public bool CheckForValidValues()
{
    dgv.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString() == Value)
            {
                  dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 192);
            }
            else
            {
                   dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Value++));
        }
    });

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        BtnShow.Enabled = true;
        dgv.Enabled = true;
    });
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bw.IsBusy == false)
    {
          progressBar1.Visible = true;
          progressBar1.Value = 0;

          BtnShow.Enabled = false;
          dgv.Enabled = false;

          progressBar1.Maximum = dgv.Rows.Count;

          bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

while the whole process goes down the DataGridView remains `Enabled=false` so that user cant change any values in datagridview.

There is usually 15,000 rows in the datagridview and that many rows to format, this takes time that is why I use a backgroundworker for it and it works **perfectly fine**  BUT when the user tries to press the ***enabled false datagridview*** couple of times, the main thread becomes unresponsive and the progressbar freezes.

Can anyone guide me how to deal with it?

Comment: Why are you using C# 3.0? Upgrade and use `async/await`

Comment: @AluanHaddad i know i am using an obselete version of Visual Studio (2008) but for some reason i have to stick with it, can you tell me a workaround for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the whole code using `Invoke`. It means you are switching to UI thread and the code is running in UI thread. Since the code is a time-consuming `for` loop, then it's blocking UI thread.

Instead of using a `BackgroundWorker`, to format cells, it's better to use [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //If this is header cell or new row, do nothing
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dgv.NewRowIndex)
        return;

    //If formatting your desired column, perform validation
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dgv.Columns["Name"].Index)
    {
        // Perform validation and change cell back color here.
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add a code snippet for it because i have no clue how to use it in this case

Comment: sorry but I am not able to understand as how "CellFormatting" is going to be called and how will it not work in UI thread as the backgroundworker did.

Comment: I didn't say CellFormatting will be run on a diferent thread. I just told you why UI is blocked in your approach. Also I showed you a better way for formatting cells. Test it and you will see the difference.

Comment: sorry i havent used this event uptill now but how is it gonna work because i am setting a datasource which will not trigger the CellFormatting event

Comment: The event belongs to DataGridView. Handle it like any other event. I've alo posted the link of MSDN page for the event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to disable the Button when it get clicked until the job done?.

Lets say your Button name is Button1,

when the user click on the **Enabled false data grid view**, use Button.enabled=false, then when the job is done use Button.enabled=true

hope that helps!

Comment: button gets enabled=false the moment it is clicked and untill the whole work is done (sorry forgot to add it in the code above)